# How to return the row number that has max value of two colums

Tags: excel

Please advise:

if I have the following example:
(column A are the colors, column B-first row of numbers(3,6,7),column C-second row of numbers(9,7,2)

```
  A         B       C     
1 Yellow    3       9
2 Pink      6       7    
3 Green     7       2
```

How can I return that color that has the maximum combined value between column B and C.
I can identify the max combined
 value with `max(b1:b3+c1:c3)` +(ctr,shift,enter), but how to get the row number where this max value is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one:

```
=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(MAX(B1:B3+C1:C3),B1:B3+C1:C3,0))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

[image]